# Change Td Class Value with JS Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, innerhtml

Here my problem using this script to retreive value

```
function GetTagValues()
{
    // Send the request
    jQuery.ajax ( { url:"/usr/private/tags.json.shtm", dataType:"json", success:TagValuesReceived, error:TagValuesError, timeout:10000 });
}
function TagValuesReceived(json)
{
    // Update value in webpage
    document.getElementById("Tank1").innerHTML = json.Tank1;
    //document.getElementById("Pump1Status").innerHTML = json.Pump1Status;
    //document.getElementById("Pump1Default").innerHTML = json.Pump1Default;
    setTimeout("GetTagValues()", 1000);
} 

function TagValuesError()
{
}

GetTagValues();
```

I would like to put the value in the td class value (replace NO VALUE by my new value)

```
<tr>
    <th>
        <strong>Flow</strong> 
        <span class="model">(FL-01011 15°C)</span> :
    </th>
    <td class="total" id="Tank1">
        <input type="text" size="6" value="NO VALUE" />
    </td>
    <td class="unite">lpm</td>
    <td class="today"></td>
</tr>
```

Right now i'm able to get the value to display, but with innerHTML it's change the way that the value is shown (normally in a box (second value) as the following image)

[image: Box vs innerHTML]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I suggest that you move the `id="tank"` to the input control and use `.value` instead of `.innerHTML`.**

Here's a JSFiddle for demonstration: https://jsfiddle.net/j10gf0mg/

Note: I changed a few things including the capitalization of functions and ids to follow standard JS coding styles so no one gets confused here. (capitalized function names identify "constructor" functions, for example)

Comment: Working fine with some corrective to fit with my code. 

as you said, better using id in input control ! ;)